# Solution of Second order ODE: theoretical question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that the way to solve a second order ODE is to find a solution that has the form $y=e^{\lambda x}$ (solution for the homogeneous equation), but I haven't understood if solutions that aren't expressed in exponential form are possible.

Comment: What happens if $\lambda$ is a double (or multiple) solution of the characteristic equation? Of course, this only applies for linear and constant-coefficients ODEs.

Comment: @Dmoreno mmmh, i know that, but my question was about the existence of a different class of solutions, that can't be expressed in the exponential form... are they possible?

Comment: For this kind of equations, the solutions will always be a linear combination of exopnential (of either real or complex exponents), unless we have multiple roots, as explained by Pupil. Maybe you are interested in other type of ODEs, such as, for instance, $x^2 y'' + x y' + y = 0$?

Comment: @Dmoreno no, it is a curiosity... i'm asking if the linear combination of exponentials fulfills the set of possible solutions.. :)

Comment: @Dmoreno I'll try to explain better the question: in my book there is written "if we have to solve $y''+ay'+by=0$, the general idea is to find solutions like $y(x)=e^{\lambda x}$". ok, but do other y(x) exist? many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your form may vary slightly depending on type of roots.

For repeated roots i.e when $b^2=4c$, the form will become: 
$$
y=\left(C_1x+C_2\right)e^{-bx/2}
$$
For complex roots i.e. when $b^2<4c$, the form will become: 
$$
y=\left[C_1\sin \left(\sqrt{|b^2-4c|}\frac{x}{2}\right)+C_2\cos \left(\sqrt{|b^2-4c|}\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]e^{-bx/2}
$$

Comment: yes, I know it, but I was asking if there are possible solution that couldn't be expressed by exponentials ... thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay. You may want to edit your question then to clarify that those solutions which do not have exponentials in them.

Answer (score 1):

It is proved that for a linear homogeneous differential equation:

$$a_n(x)\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+\cdots +a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_0(x)y=0$$

where $a_n(x)\ne 0$ and $a_i(x), i=0,\cdots, n$ are continuous on an interval $I$, then there exists a fundamental set of solution on $I$:

$$y=c_1y_1(x)+\cdots +y_n(x)$$

where $y_1(x),\cdots, y_n(x)$ are linearly independent. Since the method of $e^{\lambda x}$ gives two linearly independent solutions for a second order equation, there shouldn't be other possible solutions.

Comment: is it the unique set of solutions?

Comment: @sunrise: Yes, it is unique. They are the building blocks of the solution. That's why it is called fundamental set.

Comment: If the coefficients are constants :)

Comment: @Dmoreno: Thanks for pointing that out! Actually, if the coefficients satisfy certain criteria on the interval $I$. But constant coefficients certainly qualify.